# SETPARENT FAILED FOR FULLTEXTINDEXCOLUMN

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

Using SQL Server 2005 Enterprise. I'm trying to add columns to a full-text index created on an indexed view with schemabinding.

**Here's the full error message:**

*Cannot execute changes*

SetParent failed For FullTextIndexColumn 'geo' (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Value cannot be null

Parameter name: newParent (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I'm not sure how to proceed...Google has turned up nothing, and the "geo" field does not contain NULL values.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up dropping and recreating the view with additional fields. Not sure why that was necessary. I'll leave this question open for another day or so in case anyone can offer some insight.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. As a workaround, I materialized the view in a table.